# Select first 2 characters and replace others

Tags: sql-server

have dynamic numbers like this

```
33630521
4722829
36968
```

how can take first 2 numbers and replace others to 0 it can be varchar no problem
want result like this

```
33000000
4700000
36000
```

**tried this**

```
declare @first2 varchar(2) = (SELECT SUBSTRING('36968795', 1, 2))
declare @others varchar(100) = (SELECT SUBSTRING('36968795', 3, 100))
select @first2 + @others
```

but i stuck at replace @others to zeros because its unknown numbers may be anything

Comment: Is the input actually a varchar or an integer?

Comment: Hint: `REPLICATE('0', LEN(x))`.

Comment: SUBSTRING('36968795', 1, 2) +   REPLICATE('0',LEN('36968795')-2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done using string functions as follows:

```
Select Concat(Left(@Var, 2),Replicate('0',Len(@Var)-2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stuff`

```
declare @x varchar(10)='123456789'

select Stuff(@x,3,10,Replicate('0',Len(@x)-2))
```